# How to get border to disappear when page shrinks?

Tags: css, responsive-design, border

I was wondering if there was a pure css or bootstrap way to get a border on an element to disappear when the screen size get too small? This is because I have 3 columns that have a border in between like this `col|col|col` and when the page gets too small they look like this

```
 col
|col|
 col
```

I don't want to have the border on the middle col. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a media query on those borders and change them to `display:none` when the borders get too small.

For instance, if you had something like this:

```
.vertical-border {
  height: 200px;
}
```

You can add:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .vertical-border {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Similarly, if your borders are a property of the element itself, you can just overwrite the border property in the media query.

```
border: 0;
```

More information about media queries can be found here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: I would implement border:0;

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!